# Where can I ask questions regarding mobile hardware?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Example:

> Which mobile manufacturing company is documented to having minimum repair requests of phones in first year of purchase?

Comment: I don't think that fits any site.

Comment: Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: If no sites exists in SE networks means, then please give upvote to post owner. This is one of best principle in SE. At this time, there is no vote for post owner.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there are **NO** sites that would welcome that type of question.

Your example looks like a recommendation question. For recommendation of hardware you can visit [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) which went into beta in august 2015. Make sure to read their [Quality guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality/206#206), their [What topics can I ask here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and when in doubt check on their meta **BEFORE** posting your question there.

There are some specific sites targetting specific types of phones (like [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/), or mobile OS like [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Before you pick one from [the all sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) make sure you **read** and **comprehend** the [on Topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page and ask on their Meta first when in doubt.

Comment: I can tell you that this sort of question would be off-topic at [android.se]. (And I seem to recall a similar question was asked there not too long ago and was closed pretty quickly.)

Comment: @AlE. I edited to say more clearly NO. Is this fine?

Comment: Oh, I thought your answer was just fine. I was just trying to reinforce your message.

Comment: If no sites exists in SE networks means, then please give upvote to post owner. This is one of best principle in SE. At this time, there is no vote for post owner.

Comment: @UdanPirappu You don't give up votes to the post owner, you are supposed to vote on the merits of the post content. The question has two up votes and one down vote. My answer has two up votes. Obviously from the 104 visitors only 5 were bothered to vote which is quite understandable as the question nor the answer is particular helpful.