# Recent deleted answer doesn't show up in my profile

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Yesterday I deleted [this perfect answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239236/where-can-i-ask-questions-regarding-mobile-hardware/239240#239240) <sup>(now undeleted again)</sup> because [we wanted to shut-up a bot](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2696535#2696535).

That plan worked.

What I find strange is that in my [profile/recently delete answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/158100) the link to that answer is not present.

[image: Deleted Recent Answers]

Should I blame caching or is there another reason that the deleted answer didn't make it onto my list? My answer was posted on sep, 11th and edited on sep, 30th...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted):

> ...deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 60 days...

Not deleted in the past 60 days, but posted. Question itself is more than 2 months ago, maybe answer is also that old?